# Why there is no irqsoff option in the ftrace

Tags: linux, kernel, ftrace

I am using the ubuntu 16.04 with Linux 4.10.0-041000-generic. When I tried to output the `available_tracers` content, there was no `irqsoff` option available. I want to use this option to review an experiment in a paper. How can I get the `irqsoff` workable.

`root@XXX:/sys/kernel/debug/tracing# cat available_tracers 
hwlat blk mmiotrace function_graph wakeup_dl wakeup_rt wakeup function nop`

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to do but I have used `function_tracer` to trace execution including IRQs and you can set various irq functions in the `available_filter_functions` maybe this can help get you closer.

i.e.

```
echo function_tracer > current_tracer
cat available_filter_functions | grep "irq" 
func_1 >> set_filter_functions
echo 1 > tracing_on
xyz
echo 0 > tracing_on
cat trace
```

Comment: Thanks, I have solved it. I re-built my kernel and turn on the irqsoff option which is not included by default.